# jQuery ValidationEngine validation of inputs on tabs - prompt position and scrolling

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I have a multi-tab UI for personal info. The form encapsulates the entire "tabset"

**Initially, I was using v2.2, which did not have the `validateNonVisibleFields` flag.

I have now upgraded to 2.6.2 to take advantage of this feature.**

I made a "dummy" form that contains all my fields as hidden inputs and then made a form for each tab.
I then handle the submit to gather all the data from each form to put into the dummy form and submit it instead.

The source code is too long to post here but I've built up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/22u28vcj/

(The Address tab has an invalid field, the Country and State for the Home address need to be filled and one of the Mailing Preferences needs to be selected)

While the code I have works somewhat, after some initial testing, it seems that the prompt is being placed in the wrong position and then the form does not scroll to the field as is default.

I added a 1 second delay after switching the tab and it is still being placed in the wrong position and not scrolling.

```
if(!$("#tab1_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true})) {
    setCurrentTab(0);
    sleep(1000);
    $("#tab1_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true});
    submit = false;
} else if(!$("#tab2_form").validationEngine("validate",{validateNonVisibleFields: true})) {
    setCurrentTab(1);
    sleep(1000);
    $("#tab2_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true});
    submit = false;
} else if(!$("#tab3_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true,
    updatePromptsPosition:true})) {
    sleep(1000);
    setCurrentTab(2);
    $("#tab3_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true});
    submit = false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With which browser versions are you testing?

Comment: Chrome, IE8-IE11, Firefox, Safari. Noe of them work correctly.

Comment: Why did you make your own `sleep` function? In javascript you must use setTimeout like this: `setTimeout(function() { foo(); }, 5000);` I don't know if the problem come from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code only calls the validation once and appears to produce the desired result.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        setCurrentTab(i - 1);
        var formId = "#tab" + i + "_form";
        $(formId).removeClass('validating');
        $(formId).validationEngine("validate", {
            scroll: true,
            promptPosition: "topRight",
            showArrow: true,
            showArrowOnRadioAndCheckbox: true
        })  
    }
```

In their demos ([one example here](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoPositioning.html)) they appear to reattach the validation engine:

```
jQuery('#formID').validationEngine('hide');
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('detach');
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach');
```

Comment: In Chrome, the error popup still shows at top and you can actually see it move.

Comment: Did it in IE11 and Firefox, too.

Comment: Working on another solution. The scrolling works now but it's not clear why it's starts in the top left corner of the page.

Comment: Sad that the Engine author hasn't spoken up.

Comment: It looks like the promot is showing when the first validate call is made in the if(), then we change the tab and validate again to show the prompt on the correct field.

Comment: I also found a workaround by adding `$('.formErrorContent').hide().delay(2000).show(0);`. It's ugly but it appears to work.

Comment: I found the correct solution. It's in the `if` statement: `else if(!$("#tab3_form").validationEngine("validate", {validateNonVisibleFields: true,showPrompts:false})) {`. You need to include `showPrompts:false`.

Comment: There is no showPrompts option. showPrompt is and ACTION, like validate. I found the solution and will show you in a codepen.

Comment: `showPrompt` is an option. [Look at the engine code](http://mypage.scic.com/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.2.6.2.js) at the bottom under `// LEAK GLOBAL OPTIONS`. Also, the check the [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dnClh?editors=101). It works correctly.

Comment: Ha, it wasn't in their docs. It has a delay before it scrolls, wonder why? I took out the sleep and it still has a delay.

Comment: Calling `validationEngine` twice causes the delay. Remove the one from the if statement and there is no delay. Any other way you could check if there are errors or just call it regardless.

Comment: See this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JtHyG?editors=001 I don' tget the prompt if I do it again after clearing the prompt.

Comment: And your pen doesn't scroll on second validation. Check Home radio and try submitting again.

Comment: Not having any luck with the code now. I'll revisit in a few.

Comment: I don't recall that we came up with a solution, here.

Comment: In the end we didn't. I'll give it another look tonight.

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to redesign my site so I want to keep the tabbed version of the page.

Comment: I just retested the link in your question (http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/22u28vcj/) and it worked as desired in Chrome and IE. What's the issue with that page?

Comment: There is a 2 second delay when it scrolls to the invalid field. I cannot remove the validate call for each tab because each of them have to be validated to determine if there is an invalid field. The second validation is to show the prompt correctly

Comment: [Try this code](http://jpst.it/umuC). jsfiddle wouldn't let me update the page for whatever reason. I ended up only calling the validation once.

Comment: Don't get any validation message at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64720/discussion-between-jsuar-and-mb34).

Answer (score 0):

**The method `sleep` doesn't exist in Javascript you need to use `setTimeout` instead !**

Edit: this do not solve the problem but it's a more common way to handle the sleep function.

Replace:

```
 sleep(1000);
```

By:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        // Your code !
    }, 1000);
```

Your code become:

```js
if (!$("#tab1_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true })) {
    setCurrentTab(0);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tab1_form").removeClass('validating');
        $("#tab1_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true });
    }, 1000);
    submit = false;
} else if (!$("#tab2_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true })) {
    setCurrentTab(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tab2_form").removeClass('validating');
        $("#tab2_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true });
    }, 1000);
    submit = false;
} else if (!$("#tab3_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true })) {
    setCurrentTab(2);
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $("#tab3_form").removeClass('validating');
        $("#tab3_form").validationEngine("validate", { validateNonVisibleFields: true });
    }, 1000);
    submit = false;
}
```

The problem is that your `sleep` function is a for wich block the navigator execution, so it's totally useless and will maake think the user that your website is slow. Instead `setTimeout` will continue to execute the rest of your code and will call your function when the time given in second parameter will be elapsed.

Comment: This does not appear to solve the issue. I just test it in the original jsfiddle on Chrome. Can you post a working example?

Comment: You are right but it worked the first time i tryed, i wrote my answer too fast :). i modify my post like it was a suggestion and not an answer, thx.

Comment: No worries. But you should up vote answers that are correct. :]